# Finding the nth ugly number

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, primes, factors

I'm trying to optimize my solution to this [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/super-ugly-number/):

> Write a program to find the n<sup>th</sup> super ugly number.
>
> Super ugly numbers are positive numbers whose all prime factors are in
>   the given prime list primes of size k.

My working, accepted solution:

```
import heapq
class Solution:
    def nthSuperUglyNumber(self, n: int, primes: List[int]) -> int:
        heap = [1]
        seen = set()
        while n>=0:
            num = heapq.heappop(heap)
            n -=1
            if n == 0:
                return num 
            for p in primes:
                if num * p not in seen:
                    seen.add(num*p)
                    heapq.heappush(heap, num*p)

        return heapq.heappop(heap)
```

What are some ways to optimize it in terms of time and space complexity?

Answer (score 2):

As already explained [in this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229807/35991), there is no need to use a class with an instance method here. In addition, the convention for function names in Python is to use `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

On the other hand, this template is given on the [LeetCode submission template](https://leetcode.com/problems/super-ugly-number/), so you are not free to change it.

What you can do is to make the required solution method a wrapper for a free function (which then is universally usable):

```
def nth_super_ugly_number(n: int, primes: List[int]) -> int:
    # ...


class Solution:
    def nthSuperUglyNumber(self, n: int, primes: List[int]) -> int:
        return nth_super_ugly_number(n, primes)
```

*Generating* the ugly numbers can be separated from *counting* them (until the nth ugly number is reached) if the former is done with a *generator.* The generator is now a reusable function as well, and you might want to add a docstring comment:

```
def super_ugly_numbers(primes: List[int]) -> int:
    """Generate super ugly numbers.

    Super ugly numbers are positive integers whose all prime factors are in
    the given prime list.
    """

    heap = [1]
    seen = set()
    while True:
        num = heapq.heappop(heap)
        yield num
        for p in primes:
            if num * p not in seen:
                seen.add(num * p)
                heapq.heappush(heap, num * p)


def nth_super_ugly_number(n: int, primes: List[int]) -> int:
    ugly_numbers = super_ugly_numbers(primes)
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        next(ugly_numbers)
    return next(ugly_numbers)
```

The last function can be simplified using `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools

def nth_super_ugly_number(n: int, primes: List[int]) -> int:
    ugly_numbers = super_ugly_numbers(primes)
    return next(itertools.islice(ugly_numbers, n - 1, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Loop like a native

```
    while n>=0:
        n -=1
```

You don't actually use `n`, nor should you be manually decrementing it, so this can become

```
for _ in range(n+1):
```

### Returns

I'm not clear on why you have two `return`s. `return num` will take effect on the last iteration of the loop, so how would the other return happen at all? Probably you should remove the `if n == 0` condition and rework the place where `heappop` is called so that the `for _ in range` can completely control the loop.

### Set operations

Try this out to see what performance impact it has:

Rather than

```
        for p in primes:
            if num * p not in seen:
                seen.add(num*p)
                heapq.heappush(heap, num*p)
```

try

```
to_add = {num*p for p in primes} - seen
seen |= to_add
for a in to_add:
    heapq.heappush(heap, a)
```